# Delete (Reverse Backspace) Button

Tags: java, android

I have built a delete button in Android, just like in Windows, which removes the string on the right hand side of the cursor (one by one). (Instead of the mainstream <kbd>Backspace</kbd> which removes the left side.)

Tell me if you have any better ideas.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView.BufferType;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public Toast t, t1,t2;
    Editable a, b, d, f, a1;
    String e;
    public int c, d1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText ed;

        Button dlt;

        dlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed.clearFocus();

        dlt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onClick(View v) {

                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                boolean check = mgr.isActive(ed);
                if(check==true){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", t2.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
                }
                a = ed.getEditableText();

                b = a;
                c = ed.getSelectionStart();

                String a11 = b.toString().substring(c);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a11, t1.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                String a22 = b.toString().substring(0, c);

                boolean daj = b.toString().isEmpty();
                if (a11 != null && !a11.trim().equals("")) {

                    int strChar = a11.length();
                    String strcut = a11.substring(1, strChar);
                    e = a22.concat(strcut);

                    ed.setText(e, BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    b = ed.getEditableText();
                    ed.setSelection(c);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cool",
                            t.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Name your variables and fields meaningfully. I have no idea what `a`,`b`,`e`, etc are.
2. Don't split your variable declaration and initalization. Instead of

   > ```
   > final EditText ed;
   >
   > Button dlt;
   >
   > dlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   >
   > ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   > ```

   do

   ```
   final EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);    
   final Button dlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   ```

   And be consistent with your `final` usage. Either use it everywhere where appropriate or don't. Otherwise I start to wonder why `ed` is `final` and `dlt` is not.
3. There a [`TextUtils.isEmpty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method available on Android. Use it instead of

   > ```
   > a11 != null && !a11.trim().equals("")
   > ```
4. Use static field access. Instead of `t1.LENGTH_SHORT` use `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`. All the fields `t`,`t1` and `t2` are unnecessary.
5. All your fields should be local variables.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll surely keep your suggestions i mind the next time I write a code snippet.